# How Do I Configure Multi-lingual Metadata and Keywords

Tags: ios, localization

My app has been localized to multiple languages and is to be distributed worldwide. I'm having trouble understanding how to insert metadata and keywords that would be appropriate for each language of the many stores that it will appear in. What am I missing?

It seems that I will run out of number of allowed characters if I try to insert metadata and keywords for multiple languages all into the one field that I see for each. Is there another way to accomplish this?

I understand that keywords can't be changed once the app has been submitted/uploaded. What can I do to work around that if I want to localize my keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit your Metadata any time you want. logon to itunesconnect-> manage application -> select your application-> click on view details. In app details page you have a "Metadata and Uploads" section. next to the section title there is an `edit` button, it allow you to edit some details in metadata.[image]

And also you can add metadata in different languages. For that first you have to choose your language from the drop down menu on the right hand side. here it will list the languages that your app supports. this value is taking from your app's info.plist (means what are the languages you add in localisation). Select any language from the drop down and then press `edit` button. Here you can add metadata for that language and it will displayed on the particular store

Comment: Thanks. I was able to set the localized metadata and the events, too. I wasn't able to do this before the app had been uploaded.

Comment: okey.... it was because once the app is uploaded then only the itunesconnect will know what are the languages supported by your app.